# Reuse vector in loop outputs "Killed" after few iteration

Tags: c++, vector

I have a loop that declares a vector at the beginning, writes data to it via push_back().  At the beginning of the loop I redeclare the vector to size 0.  Code is giving me "Killed" after a few iteration of the loop.  Can anyone show me proper way to reuse this vector?

```
.
.
.
//forever loop
while (1) {

        std::vector < unsigned char * > image_vector(0);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        // initialize variables
        steady_clock::time_point start_second = now;
        steady_clock::time_point start_next_second = now;
        steady_clock::time_point end_time = now + std::chrono::milliseconds(dT2 * 1000); // time to end capture sequence

        while (1) {

            // if start of current second past end_time exit loop
            if (start_next_second >= end_time) {
                cout << "Done capturing..." << endl;
                break;
            }

            // incriment by 1s for start of next second
            start_next_second += std::chrono::milliseconds(1000); //start of next second

            for (int y = 0; y < dT1; y++) {
                unsigned char * data = new unsigned char[Camera.getImageBufferSize()];
                Camera.grab();
                Camera.retrieve(data);
                image_vector.push_back(data); /**********Writing data to vector********/
            }

        }

        /* Save all images in vector to disk */
        int index = 1;
        for (std::vector < unsigned char * > ::iterator it = image_vector.begin(); it != image_vector.end(); ++it) {
            std::stringstream fn;
            fn << "images/[Pi]image";
            fn << index;
            fn << getExtension(Camera);
            saveImage(fn.str(), * it, Camera);
            cerr << "Saving " << fn.str() << endl;
            //delete[] * it;
            index++;
        }


        cout<< "Capture done, sleeping 5 seconds before next capture routine." << endl;
        usleep(5000000); //sleep 5 sec before next capture routine
}
```

Comment: What you need is a vector<vector<unsigned char>>, also you delete[] line is commented out so yeah youre definitely leaking memory

Comment: Are you sure about the vector<vector<unsigned char>> ?  The code is working perfectly fine it just dies after a few loops.

Comment: *"The code is working perfectly fine it just dies ..."* - do you realize the concrete contradiction in that statement? Borgleader's advice is solid. A vector of vectors would be applicable for this, and easily solve the memory leak. Friends don't let friends self-manage raw memory allocations in modern C++. Either use standard containers (like `std::vector`, or smart pointers). See [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing the two dashed lines in front of `delete[] * it;` solved the problem.

Comment: What "dashed lines"?  This is not a helpful answer.